# find a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ such that $A \neq I_3$ and $A^{197}=I_3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

find a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ such that $A \neq  I_3$ and $A^{197}=I_3$.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 4):

Think of rotation matrices, in particular rotation by $\theta=\frac{2\pi}{197}$. Note $197$ is prime.

Comment: someone downvoted my answer. I am not sure why? At the very least (it is helpful for all parties concerned) one should provide a reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 4):

Choose any $\alpha \neq 1$ such that $\alpha^{197}=1.$ Then concider $\alpha I_3.$

Answer (score 0):

if $A = \pmatrix{\cos(2\pi/197)& -\sin (2\pi/197)& 0\\\sin(2\pi/197& \cos (2\pi/197)& 0\\0&0&1
 },$  then $A^{197} = I_3.$