# Identity matrix and matrix to the $n$th power

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am quite unfamiliar with the idea of matrices to the $n$th power so far but I hope someone here could elaborate a little bit on this problem I've come across.

The idea is that we have our square $3\times3$ matrix $A$ and we need to satisfy these two conditions.

1. $A\neq I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix $3\times3$)
2. $A^{197} = I$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix $3\times3$)

Comment: I think its already there ...http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1516318/find-a-3-times-3-matrix-a-such-that-a-neq-i-3-and-a197-i-3/1516358#1516358

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try making $A$ a rotation matrix.

Comment: Well I´ve tried it with some matrices and one matrix I think should work was this one:  $\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&1&1\end{pmatrix}.$
Which isn´t really a rotation matrix but close enough. I tried it with a rotation matrix, that determines rotation around the first coordinate axis which looks like $ \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}.$ but that didn´t work.
Correct me if I am wrong here but A^{197} should be same as A^3 power in this case. Considering we are working only with zeroes and ones we should just care if the exponent is odd or even.

Comment: Why are we "working only with zeroes and ones"?

Comment: We are not, it is just convinient in this case.

Comment: It's only convenient if it is possible to find an answer of that form

Comment: Think in terms of linear maps. We want a map that, when applied $197$ times, brings things back to where they started.